# Zend Framework Multiple Table Query

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I am looking to execute this statement via Zend Framework. As I understand it, I can use Zend_Db_Select. Is it possible to use Zend_Db_Table?

Three tables: classes, students, and class_students

select classes.name, students.student_id, students.fname, students.lname from students, classes, class_students where class_students.student_id=students.student_id AND class_students.class_id=classes.class_id;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, is possible - Zend_Db_Table provides you with an interface to execute a variety of operations on a table. For example, considering the multiple table selection that you want to perform, and assuming you have your db adapter properly configured, we can end up with something like the following:

```
$table = new Model_DbTable_Classes(); // which extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
$select = $table->select()->setIntegrityCheck(false);
$select->join('class_students', 'class_students.class_id = classes.class_id')
       ->join('students', 'student.student_id = class_students.student_id')
       ->where('classes.class_id = ?', 1)
       ->where('student.student_id = ?', 10);

$result = $table->fetchAll($select);

print_r($result->toArray());
```

For this particular case I wouldn't use the Zend_Db_Table though, I tend to use Zend_Db_Table when I need just to take actions upon one single table. As for multiple table selections I'd rather go with db select, or structuring my query old-school-fashioned (SQL string), and fetch it using my db object.

Hope it helps :)

M.